# Can't have an ivar with a name of description in Objective-C description method?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to implement the Objective-C description method for my NSObject-derived object.

However, my derived object has an ivar of name description.  And for some reason this is causing a crash.

```
- (NSString *) description {

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    [output appendFormat:@"MyObject.description = %@\n", self.description];

    return output;
}
```

Why would this be an issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Short Answer:*** The crash is a result of a stack overflow because your `-description` method calls itself repeatedly. To do what you want to do (accessing the ivar from within the description method), you should *not* use the prefix `self.` in front of the ivar.

***More Detail:***

In Objective-C, `self.description` is shorthand for `[self description]`. Using the dot-syntax informs the compiler that you want to access a property named `description`, and *not* the ivar itself.

Comment: `this`? Think you mean `self` ;-) (Though `this` is the C++ equiv, sorta). nm, you fixed it.

Comment: @NSGod: Already fixed, but thank you for pointing it out. I make that mistake all the time. I cut my teeth on C++, so `this` pops out automatically `:)`

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue because you're creating an infinite loop. `self.description` will call [self description], which is exactly the method you're within. Hence you have the method calling itself repeatedly.

```
- (NSString *) description {

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    [output appendFormat:@"super's description = %@\n", [super description]];
    [output appendFormat:@"MyObject.description = %@\n", description];

    return output;
}
```

You can access the instance variable directly, rather than using self.description. Also, I added an extra line to show how you can call super's description method (which doesn't create an infinite loop).

Comment: +1 from me. Good point about the call to `[super description]`